# Why do I need to open all expansion panes in a list view, else they give null? - Gluon JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

I don't know if this is a code issue or a bug. But this picture shows us a `Glisten List View` where I have included `Glisten DropdownButtons` inside a `ExpandedPaneContainer` etc.

[image]

The issue here is that I need to open the first the first expansion pane, then the second one, named `Layer 2`, and then the third one, named `Layer 3`.

I cannot directly open `Layer 2` or `Layer 3` at the beginning. After I have open all expanded panes and close them, then I can open them again in a random order.

**Question:**

Why does it behave like this? Is it a bug?
If you want to run the program, just download the code from here: https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Deeplearning2C and then create a new file inside the software, by clicking the "pen"-icon. Give it a name and then go to "Configurations -> Layer Configuration". Try to open the last expansion panel at the bottom first.

Here is the method I use when I add all these `expansion panes` inside a `expandedPaneContainer`. I know there is lot of code, but the idea is that:

1. Create a expansion panel
2. Add the expansion panel into expanded panel container
3. Create a collapsed panel and set its labels etc.
4. Set the collapsed panel to expansion panel collapsed content
5. Create a expanded panel and set a grid pane into it
6. Add a labels at column 0, row `j`, and drop down buttons box at column 1 and row `j` inside the grid pane.
7. Repeat the process again

```java
private void addLayer() {
    /*
     * Create a expanded panels from these 
     */
    String[] dropDownTypes =  dL4JSerializableConfiguration.getDropdownTypes(); 

    /*
     * New expansions panel and add it to the expansions panel container
     */
    ExpansionPanel expansionPanel = new ExpansionPanel();
    expansionPanelContainer.getItems().add(expansionPanel);

    /*
     * Create an collapsed panel and first set a label with the name of the layer index e.g. layer 0, layer 1 etc and the layer type
     */
    CollapsedPanel collapsedPanel = new CollapsedPanel();
    collapsedPanel.getTitleNodes().add(0, new Label("Layer " + expansionPanelContainer.getItems().size())); // Layer index
    collapsedPanel.getTitleNodes().add(1, new Label("DenseLayer")); // Layer type
    expansionPanel.setCollapsedContent(collapsedPanel); // Set collapsed panel into expansion panel

    /*
     * Create an expanded panel and begin to set a grid pane into it
     */
    ExpandedPanel expandedPanel = new ExpandedPanel();
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    expandedPanel.setContent(gridPane);
    expansionPanel.setExpandedContent(expandedPanel);

    /*
     * Add all drop downs and labels
     */
    for(int j = 0; j < dropDownTypes.length; j++) {
        /*
         * Create the  element label and set its position inside the grid
         */
        Label elementLabel = new Label(dropDownTypes[j]);
        gridPane.add(elementLabel, 0, j); // To the left

        /*
         * Create the drop down button and add the elements and set its position inside the grid
         */
        DropdownButton elementDropdown = new DropdownButton();
        if(dropDownTypes[j].equals(dropDownTypes[0])) { // Layer types
            elementDropdown.getItems().addAll(new MenuItem("DenseLayer"), new MenuItem("LSTM"), new MenuItem("OutputLayer"));
        }else if(dropDownTypes[j].equals(dropDownTypes[1])) { // Inputs
            for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
                elementDropdown.getItems().add(new MenuItem(String.valueOf(i)));
        }else if(dropDownTypes[j].equals(dropDownTypes[2])) { // Outputs
            for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
                elementDropdown.getItems().add(new MenuItem(String.valueOf(i)));
        }else if(dropDownTypes[j].equals(dropDownTypes[3])) { // Activations
            for(Activation activation : Activation.values())
                elementDropdown.getItems().add(new MenuItem(activation.name()));
        }else if(dropDownTypes[j].equals(dropDownTypes[4])) { // Loss functions
            for(LossFunctions.LossFunction lossFunction : LossFunctions.LossFunction.values())
                elementDropdown.getItems().add(new MenuItem(lossFunction.name()));
        }       
        gridPane.add(elementDropdown, 1, j); // To the middle
    }
}
```